# Is the @Dependent CDI annotation inherited by subclasses?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I have these classes:

```
@Dependent
public abstract class ClassA{...}

public class ClassB extends ClassA{...}

public class ClassC{
  @Inject
  private ClassB classB;
}
```

So, will the instance of `classB` injected in instance of `classC` be destroyed when instance of `classC` will be destroyed? In other words is the 
`@Dependent` CDI annotation inherited by subclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the relevant section in the [CDI 1.0 spec](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/inheritance.html). Note the second bullet point:

> Suppose a class X is extended directly or indirectly by the bean class
>   of a managed bean or session bean Y.
>
> - If X is annotated with a qualifier type, stereotype or interceptor binding type Z then Y inherits the annotation if and only if Z
>     declares the `@Inherited` meta-annotation and neither Y nor any
>     intermediate class that is a subclass of X and a superclass of Y
>     declares an annotation of type Z.
>     (This behavior is defined by the Java Language Specification.)
> - If X is annotated with a scope type Z then Y inherits the annotation if and only if Z declares the `@Inherited` meta-annotation
>     and neither Y nor any intermediate class that is a subclass of X and a
>     superclass of Y declares a scope type.
>     (This behavior is different to what is defined in the Java Language
>     Specification.)
>
> A scope type explicitly declared by X and inherited by Y from X takes
>   precedence over default scopes of stereotypes declared or inherited by
>   Y.

As the `@Dependent` pseudo-scope does indeed have the `@Inherited` meta-annotation, the scope is inherited if nor the subclass nor any intermediary class have a scope annotation (as in your example).

Since the `@Dependent` scope is the default scope, it doesn't matter too much either way, I think.

Comment: So, do I understand you right - if I want instance of ClassB be destroyed when instance of ClassC is destroyed I must do `@Inherited public class ClassB extends ClassA{...}`?

Comment: No. `@Inherited` is a meta-annotation on the `@Dependent` annotation type. You don't have to do anything. Your code will behave as you expect it to, even without the `@Dependent` annotation itself (since it's the default scope).